# better way of handling nested list

Tags: python

```
my_list = [ [1,2,3,4,5,6], [1,3,4],[34,56,56,56]]
for item in my_list:
    var1,var2,var3,var4,var5,var6 = None
     if len(item) ==1:
          var1 = item[0]
     if len(item) == 2:
          var1 = item[0]
          var2  = item[1]
     if len(item) == 3:
         var1 = item[0]
         var2 = item[1]
         var3 = item[2]
     if len(item) == 4:
        var1 = item[0]
        var2 = item[1]
        var3 = item[2]
        var4 = item[3]
    fun(var1,var2,var3,var4,var5,var6)
```

I have a function

```
def fun(var1, var2 = None, var3 = None, var4 = None, var5=None, var6= None)
```

Depending upon the values in my inner list. I am passing it to function. 
I hope I made it clear.

Thanks

Comment: It's not ok. Please tell us what you're trying to do. Thank you.

Comment: depending upon the size of list I am trying to get the values.

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Calls](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#calls) and [Function definitions](http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#function-definitions) in the [Python documentation](http://docs.python.org/index.html), specifically:

> If the syntax *expression appears in
>   the function call, expression must
>   evaluate to a sequence. Elements from
>   this sequence are treated as if they
>   were additional positional
>   arguments....
>
> ---
>
> If the syntax **expression appears in the function call, expression must evaluate to a mapping, the contents of which are treated as additional keyword arguments....
>
> ---
>
> ...A function call always assigns values
>   to all parameters mentioned in the
>   parameter list, either from position
>   arguments, from keyword arguments, or
>   from default values. If the form
>   “*identifier” is present, it is
>   initialized to a tuple receiving any
>   excess positional parameters,
>   defaulting to the empty tuple. If the
>   form “**identifier” is present, it is
>   initialized to a new dictionary
>   receiving any excess keyword
>   arguments, defaulting to a new empty
>   dictionary.

### Example 1

You most likely need the following, since your arguments are simple integers:

```
my_list = [[1,2,3,4,5,6],[1,3,4],[34,56,56,56]]

def func(*var):
    for arg in var:
        print arg,
    print

for args in my_list:
    func(*args)
```

#### Output 1

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 
1 3 4 
34 56 56 56
```

### Example 2

The next example shows you can fill in any number of arguments to a function with defaults:

```
my_list = [[1,2,3,4,5,6],[1,3,4],[34,56,56,56]]

def func(var1=None,var2=None,var3=None,var4=None,var5=None,var6=None):
    print var1,var2,var3,var4,var5,var6

for args in my_list:
    func(*args)
```

#### Output 2

```
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 3 4 None None None
34 56 56 56 None None
```

### Example 3

You can even fill them in out-of-order with the `**` syntax:

```
my_list = [dict(var1=1,var5=5,var6=6),dict(var2=2,var4=4)]

def func(var1=None,var2=None,var3=None,var4=None,var5=None,var6=None):
    print var1,var2,var3,var4,var5,var6

for args in my_list:
    func(**args)
```

#### Output 3

```
1 None None None 5 6
None 2 None 4 None None
```

Answer (score 1):

EDIT - the real question is - my have function which takes def fun(var1, var2=None, var3= None,var4=None,var5 = None, var6 = None): so if my inner list contain only 1 element then function takes var1 only. but if more then 1 element in my inner list it is pass to the function

What you would like to use is the * operator

```
fun(*l)
```

is equivalent to

```
fun(l[0],l[1],....)
```

So you want to use: `fun(*my_list[0])` for the first, and so on
To use it for all the lists inside my_list do:

```
for i in my_list:
    fun(*i)
```

Comment: but if I know the length of the list I can use indexing. basically My inner list can be from 1to 6 elements. so if my innerlist contain only 1 element then its should get assign to var1. if 2 then var1 and var2.  and so on.

Comment: but sequences of variables with names like `var1`, `var2`... `varX` is the whole point of arrays.  whatever format you think you are changing too is not better.  can you just tell us what the end goal is here?

Comment: my have function which takes def fun(var1, var2=None, var3= None,var4=None,var5 = None):   so if my inner list contain only 1 element then function takes var1 only. but if more then 1 element in my inner list it is pass to the function. I hope I made it clear.

Comment: ok, thats a good question.  why dont you edit your question to ask this?