# what does "*" mean in Python?

Tags: python

I came across with a line in python.

```
            self.window.resize(*self.winsize)
```

What does the "*" mean in this line?
I haven't seen this in any python tutorial.

Comment: See [Unpacking Argument Lists](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html?highlight=unpacking#unpacking-argument-lists) in the online [Python Tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/index.html).

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4496712/better-way-of-handling-nested-list/4497363#4497363.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does ** and * do for python parameters?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-and-do-for-python-parameters)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One possibility is that self.winsize is list or tuple. The * operator unpacks the arguments out of a list or tuple.

See : http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists

Ah: There is an SO discussion on this: [Keyword argument in unpacking argument list/dict cases in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3141152/keyword-argument-in-unpacking-argument-list-dict-cases-in-python)

An example:

```
>>> def f(a1, b1, c1): print a1
... 
>>> a = [5, 6, 9]
>>> f(*a)
5
>>>
```

So unpacks elements out of list or tuple. Element can be anything.

```
>>> a = [['a', 'b'], 5, 9]
>>> f(*a)
['a', 'b']
>>>
```

Another small addition : If a function expects explicit number of arguments then the tuple or list should match the number of elements required.

```
>>> a = ['arg1', 'arg2', 'arg3', 'arg4']
>>> f(*a)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: f() takes exactly 3 arguments (4 given)
>>>
```

To accept multiple arguments without knowing number of arguments:

```
>>> def f(*args): print args
... 
>>> f(*a)
('arg1', 'arg2', 'arg3', 'arg4')
>>>
```

Comment: @Falmarri : Thanks a lot! I was not sure and did not want to be sound know all.

Comment: @lyrae: Not at all. It will work with anything as elements of list or tuple. try it out.

Answer (score 2):

Here, `self.winsise` is a tuple or a list with exactly the same number of elements as the number of arguments `self.window.resize` expects. If the number is either less or more, an exception will be raised.

That said, we can create functions to accept any number of arguments using similar trick. See [this](http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2008/01/how-to-use-args-and-kwargs-in-python/).

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't have to be a tuple or list, any old (finite) iterable thing will do.

Here is an example passing in a generator expression

```
>>> def f(*args):
...     print type(args), repr(args)
... 
>>> f(*(x*x for x in range(10)))
<type 'tuple'> (0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81)
```